# Eclipse - changing resource while in a IResourceChangeEvent

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to change a resource while inside a

> IResourceChangeEvent

Is there any way to do it?

I tried calling a `WorkspaceModifyOperation` from the `ResourceChangeListener` but I get

> org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException:The resource
>   tree is locked for modifications.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the message tells you, you can't change a resource during another resource change. However, you can prepare a workspace job that will change the resource later and schedule it. The resource will then be changed when other pending workspace edits are completed.

Comment: `WorkspaceJob` works as intended, I simple scheduled a job and it now doesn't fail with exception.